# XMPP server giving error "No response from server"

Tags: xmpp, smack

hi i am using smack.jar to connect to my gmail server. but xmppconnection.connet() is failing and it says that server is not responding . i am attaching the log. please help me out.

Exception in thread "main" Connection failed. No response from server.: 
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.startup(PacketReader.java:164)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initConnection(XMPPConnection.java:945)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:904)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1415)
    at JabberSmackAPI.login(JabberSmackAPI.java:29)
    at JabberSmackAPI.main(JabberSmackAPI.java:79)

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, the server isn't returning this error, because you haven't connected to the server yet.

It might be a configuration problem.  If your server doesn't have a client DNS SRV record (e.g. `_xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com`), then you'll need to pass the `XMPPConnection` object a `ConnectionConfiguration` with the name of the machine to connect to for your domain.

It is also possible that this is a network problem (connectivity, routing, firewall, etc.).  To test for this, try commands like this on the command line:

```
% dig +short _xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com SRV
5 0 5222 talk.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 talk2.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 talk1.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 talk3.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 talk4.l.google.com.
% telnet talk.l.google.com 5222
Trying 74.125.155.125...
Connected to talk.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
>
```

Note that you type the greater-than character.  Most XMPP servers will disconnect you immediately at this point, since you've sent them XML that is not well-formed.

If you've got a network problem, you'll see something like this:

```
Trying 74.125.155.125...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.155.125: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually it was a firewall issue.

Comment: @SPB, I know its been a while, but what were your firewall issues because we're getting this error intermittently and some chats are dropping and there is a firewall between the servers.

Comment: Check to make sure your firewall is not blocking connections, timing out connections, or eating the FIN and RST packets that the server can send.